# I do care about the format of the questions

Tags: discussion, editing

[My edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/6205) was rejected for this reason:

> Let's wait until we find out what the symbols mean...

Which I failed to make sense of.

While the user who rejected the edit, made the same edit in the body but refused to edit the title. They could simply approve the edit and re-edit afterwards. The question is now edited to something similar to what I suggested.

I'm not trying to make a mountain out of a molehill but I realized the rejected and approved edits of a user are recorded under a so-called "editor stats" and this is the third time someone rejected my edit, mistakenly. 
I just think they should be more careful about it.

Comment: Your claim is incorrect. http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/140057/revisions show who edited what, and there is no indication that anyone edited the body of the question.

Comment: I may well be missing something, but it appears that the person who rejected your edit only edited the title and not in the way you had suggested; a second person subsequently edited the title in a way very similar to what you'd suggested (I see no edits to the body of the question).

Comment: @Isaac: The title edit was *before* the proposed edit.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: You are correct and I hadn't noticed that.  I don't think it changes my statement much, though, nor does it help my lack of understanding of the dissonance between what's stated in this question and what I see in the history.

Comment: @Isaac: No worries: just trying to clarify the sequence of events. I agree that the statement about edits to the body does not match the history.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I rejected the edit; as I recall, the edit converted the "Cn(A)" to math in title and did little more. My feeling was that this was (i) a minor change; and (ii) one that could very well have turned out to be moot once we found out the meaning of the symbols; it would then require a *further* edit to clarify and fix the title.

I know that I'm the one who dropped the "prop.logic" from the title (see note below: that happened *before* you proposed your edit), but that was because we don't put the subject area as a preface in the title... that's what tags were for.

I don't think I rejected your edit "mistakenly." I knew exactly what I was doing and *why* I was doing so. We may not agree on whether this was a good reason, but that's not the same as saying that I made a mistake in doing so.

*Note:* I edited the title at 19:59:10Z. You proposed your edit at 20:01:31Z, *after* I had already edited the title. Your edit proposal does not seem to include *any* edit in the body, and I certainly did no edit in the body. So I did not reject the edit and *then* "did the same edit in the body". There *was* no edit in the body.

Comment: P.S. I wasn't on-line, and I would not have gotten any say on Asaf's edit in any case, since he's a high-rep editor. If I had, since it happened before the OP clarified the meaning, I might have rejected it as well...

Comment: What does the Z stand for in the edit time?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff. I believe it stands for "Zulu"; it means it is taken in the "zero meridian" i.e., Universal time; that's what stackexchange uses to determine the "day and time". If you hover over a time info (e.g., where it says "answered xxx mins ago", or in your comment where it says "xxx mins ago") a pop-up will give you the zulu time.

Comment: Yes, I tend to do that, but I never knew what the Z stood for. Thanks.

Comment: I see, I thought you were the one who edited the LaTeX in the body. Sorry.

Comment: @Gigili: As of this writing, **nobody** has edited the body! (see [the summary](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/140057/revisions)). The original post **already** contained LaTeX in the body.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: You're right. I saw you edited it and I didn't check how and which part! Sorry again, I'll be more careful next time.